# postgresql 9.5 how to update field on pg_settings table?

Tags: postgresql

I copy postgres database but forgot to set port then i tried to update pg_settings using :

```
update pg_settings set setting=5453 where name='port';
```

then i got :

> ERROR:  parameter "port" cannot be changed without restarting the server

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The pg_settings is read only view - you cannot to change configuration by `UPDATE` statement. The fields can be changed by statements:

   ```
   ALTER SYSTEM SET field TO value;
   ALTER DATABASE dbnane SET field TO value;
   ```

   or you can directly edit the `postgresql.conf` file.
2. Some fileds like *port*, *shared_buffers*, ... requires the server restart. The your error message shows it.

Comment: Thanks @PavelStehule