# How to increase column name width limit in AWS RDS Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I am trying to increase the length of column name in postgres. On local server, I can just do it by editing max_identifier_length by using ALTER SYSTEM command. But when we are using RDS, the admin/master does not have the permission to do so. Although RDS provides parameter group where many parameters are listed for configuration, but max_identifier_length is missing. The bigger issue is there is no way to add a new parameter to parameter group.

Comment: You can not increase the column name length with `alter system` in Postgres. If you want to increase that limit, you have to compile Postgres yourself

Comment: Besides, if 63 characters are not enough for you, you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe. Oracle used to say if 30 characters aren't enough you are doing something wrong - and then they increased the limit to 128 ;)

Comment: 30 is cutting it close, but I fundamentally agree. Not everything Oracle says is wrong...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I understand that 63 characters is good amount of limit, but there are certail use cases that do require us to go beyond this limit and hence I need to increase the limit to length of column name.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes we can increase the length by using alter system. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449831/4190333 . Here if we update max_identifier_length, we could increase the limit.

Comment: @SidharthChhawchharia: no, you can **not** change it that way. Not all settings can be changed through ALTER SYSTEM and `max_identifier_length` is one of them. If you had tried, you would have seen that it results in "*ERROR: parameter "max_identifier_length" cannot be changed"*